# Resources for hoodie design related to theoretical CS

Tags: soft-question

I have to design a hoodie for my computer science batch, and I want it to be related to Theoretical computer science. I don't want to slap on some text with HTML-like angle brackets, but actually want something cool + nerdy that only people with some basic knowledge of CS might understand. I would be grateful, if you could give some suggestion, resources for ideas, or links to similar products.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found [this tattoo](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/y-combinator) pretty daring. Would work on a hoodie.

Comment: This answer could be much improved if it included more than just a link.

Answer (score 2):

As an undergraduate student, I was a bit mystified by the occurrence of the notion of entropy (from physics) into theoretical computer science (at the time, for the description of the optimal compression of a text with $n_i$ occurrences (summing to $n=\sum_{i\in[1..k]}n_i$) of each symbol $i\in[1..k]$ by [prefix free codes](https://www.scribd.com/doc/20852918/Huffman-1952-Minimum-Redundancy-Codes), such as the one described by [David A. Huffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Huffman)) and its (at the time to me) occult definition: $${\cal H}(n_1,\ldots,n_k) = \sum_{i\in[1..k]} \frac{n_i}{n} \log_2\frac{n}{n_i}.$$ Since then, I have learned to respect its potency and adequacy in measuring the (des)equilibrium of probability and frequency distributions, and I have used it to measure the spaced used by [compressed data structures](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2012.08.010), the time used by [adaptive algorithms](https://doi.org/10.1145/1328911.1328915) (in internal and [external memory](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jda.2015.11.001)), sometimes in [convoluted ways](https://doi.org/10.3390/a13010012), and even in [instance optimality results](https://doi.org/10.1145/3046673).

[image: Entropy Formula in Theoretical Computer Science]

In 2013, for a colleague's birthday anniversary, I drew quickly a feminine character holding an equation often used in our research, one of the definition of the entropy of a vector of integers. At the time I wrote on my [blog](https://jyby.blogspot.com/2013/08/tnt-and-entropy.html) "*I hope that he will hang it in his office so that it helps his students to memorize it!*", and a few years later, a PhD student admitted that he searched on the web for the blog post to find back the formula :).

The definition of the entropy that I used in this drawing, $$n{\cal H}(n_1,\ldots,n_k) = n\log_2 n - \sum_{i\in[1..k]} n_i \log_2 n_i,$$ is a bit atypical (one typically normalizes both sides of the equation by $n$, and combines the two $\log$ terms into one, maybe so that to make it closer to the definition used by statistical physicists). I like this formulation better because it highlights the terms measuring the imbalance of the distribution, and give an intuition into the various analysis which lead to such a formula.

Feel free to use either the formula itself or the drawing: I would be honored! (Do let me know if you do!)